# If $f \colon K \rightarrow L$ be a chain equivalence then $H_n (f) \colon H_n (K) \rightarrow H_n (L)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

> **Problem:** If $f \colon K \rightarrow L$ be a chain equivalence then $H_n (f) \colon H_n (K) \rightarrow H_n (L)$ is an isomorphism, in which, $H_n (K) = C_n (K) / B_n (K)$ is the homological module of $K$.

**My question:** Is there another way that is shorter to prove that? I just find out the simplest way that is, check that $H_n (f)$ be a homomorphism, injective, surjective, then conclude that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: As you have observed "homomorphism, injective, surjective" is **definition** of isomorphism.. I do not understand why you think this is the simplest way... Do you have any other method in your mind?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I realized the property of a chain equivalence. If $f$ be a chain equivalence, then exists a chain morphism $g \colon L \rightarrow K$ such that $gf \approx 1_K$ and $fg \approx 1_L$ (from the definition of a chain equivalence). I think from this property, we can prove the problem easier.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik In deed, $fg \approx 1_L \Rightarrow H_n (f) H_n (g) = 1_{H_n (L)}$ and $gf \approx 1_K \Rightarrow H_n (g) H_n (f) = 1_{H_n (K)}$, but I'm not sure that  enough to complete the proof. It's just my idea.

Comment: Of course that's enough to complete the proof. You have proved that $H_n(f)$ had an inverse : that's the definition of isomorphism